# Best way to convert XML and flatten to JSON

Tags: c#, json, xml, xml-deserialization

I have an XML file in the following format:

```
<root>
    <foos>
        <foo>
            <id>1</id>
            <number>1245</number>
        </foo>
        <foo>
            <id>2</id>
            <number>6743</number>
        </foo>
        <foo>
            <id>3</id>
            <number>2245</number>
        </foo>
    </foos>
    <bars>
        <bar>
            <id>4</id>
            <number>123</number>
        </bar>
        <bar>
            <id>5</id>
            <number>321</number>
        </bar>
    </bars>
</root>
```

Note that number of nodes like `foos` and `bars` are large.
I would like to parse this structure into a JSON in the following format:

```
{
    foos: [
        {
            id: 1,
            number: 1245
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            number: 6743
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            number: 2245
        }
    ],
    bars: [
        {
            id: 4,
            number: 123
        },
        {
            id: 5,
            number: 321
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried to achieve that with [NewtonSoft.Json](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertXmlToJson.htm) and it works fine except the nodes aren't flattened as I would like and I end-up with the following JSON:

```
{
    foos: { foo: [
        {
            id: 1,
            number: 1245
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            number: 6743
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            number: 2245
        } }
    ],
    bars: { bar: [
        {
            id: 4,
            number: 123
        },
        {
            id: 5,
            number: 321
        } }
    ]
}
```

Any tips on how to achieve that structure without having to iterate through all nodes like `foos` and `bars` and flatten it manually?

Comment: If something "…works fine, except…", it actually does _not_ work fine.

Comment: It's not even a valid json what you want get

Comment: *I have tried to achieve that with NewtonSoft.Json and it works fine* -- can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: @Tinwor the only reason it isnt valid is because the keys are not between quotes. Is that it? What did you mean?

Comment: @dbc just follow the link: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertXmlToJson.htm

Comment: @UweKeim What I meant is that the Newtonsoft function worked fine on its purpose but it wasnt what I wanted... Stop being so picky... ¬¬

Answer (score 1):

You could use Json.Net's [LINQ-to-JSON API](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) (JObjects) to build the JSON from the XML:

```
var root = XElement.Parse(xml);
var json = new JObject(
    root.Elements().Select(x =>
        new JProperty(x.Name.ToString(),
            new JArray(
                x.Elements().Select(y =>
                    new JObject(
                        y.Elements().Select(z =>
                            new JProperty(z.Name.ToString(),
                                new JValue(int.Parse(z.Value))
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
).ToString();
```

Demo fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jPjnuY

Comment: The problem is not all nodes are like foos and bars, some are already flat. But that is a great direction you gave me there. Will try to manage something out of it, Thanks!